# How to keep the state of a FormGroup in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a FormGroup set up like so:

```js
const forms = new FormGroup( {
    name: new FormControl(''),
    address: new FormControl(''),
});
```

Lets say I want to only save some part of the form, but instead of resetting the entire form to the database values, I want to direct the user back to their unfinished changes. How can I save the 'state' of this FormGroup, so that I can set all the formControls back to it at a later time?

So far, I have just been finding success doing it individually which is a pain:

```js
const unsavedName = this.forms.controls.name.value;
//and then when I want to reset state:
this.forms.controls.name.setValue(unsavedName);
```

Which works great for just one value, but I would like a way to grab all the values in the FormGroup.

Thanks

Comment: You can get the entire form with something like const state = this.forms.value and restore a form with this.form.patchValues(state). Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```js
const formValues = {...this.form.value};
```

This will give you an object that contains all values in your form.

and you can use `this.form.setValue(formValues)` to set the values again.

To set few values you can use `this.form.patchValue({ name: 'name'})`

Comment: Hmm this doesn't seem to be working actually, yet manually setting a FormControl is..

Comment: [Refer here](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/setvalue-patchvalue-in-angular/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Use patchvalues function

```
updateProfile() {
  this.profileForm.patchValue({
    firstName: 'Nancy',
    address: {
      street: '123 Drew Street'
    }
  });
}
```

https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms